# Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline Jenkinsfile detect Git repo that launched job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a multi branch pipeline configuration job working fine so far....

However every single repository has exactly the same jenkinsfile except for the git repo name.

a typical jenkinsfile looks like:

```
node('docker-slave') {
    withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: 'NEXUS', usernameVariable: 'NEXUS_USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'NEXUS_PASSWORD']]) {
        git url: 'git@bitbucket.org:myco/myprob.git', branch: env.branch_name, credentialsId: '08df8ab41de0', variable: 'CREDENTIALS'
        stage 'Test'
        sh 'env > env.txt'
        sh 'cat env.txt'
        sh 'make verify'
    }
}
```

What I'd like to do is detect which git repo triggered the build so I don't have to hardcode it in the jenkinsfile.

So what I'd like is to change the git line to something like (notice GIT_URL):

```
 git url: env.GIT_URL, branch: env.branch_name, credentialsId: '08df8ab41de0', variable: 'CREDENTIALS'
```

This gets me closer to my eventual goal of storing my Jenkinsfile in a common location instead of having to copy it repo to repo and modify it repo to repo.

Any ideas?

Thanks
phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out that in the script the following code does exactly what I need:

```
checkout sum
```

The git url line isn't needed....

so in the end the code looks like:

```
node('docker-slave') {
     withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: 'NEXUS', usernameVariable: 'NEXUS_USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'NEXUS_PASSWORD']]) {
     checkout scm
     stage 'Test'
     sh 'make verify'
}
```